# ¿Como reemplazar espacios vacios en un Array de dobles? - C#

Tags: c#, array

espero que me puedan ayudar con un problema que tengo en c#. Estoy creando un programa para numeros pseudoaleatorios, y todos estos numeros se guardan dentro de un Array de dobles. El problema que presento, es una vez que ejecuto el programa, este trata de buscar dentro del Array todos los numeros despues del punto decimal para hacer una comparacion. Por ejemplo (0.1111,0.2222,0.333..), la cuestion es que deja de funcionar una vez que llega a un numeo entero, ya que aunque lo tengo redondeado no logra encontrar nada despues del punto decimal, y es ahi cuando falla. Entonces quiero saber, si existe la manera de poder asignar un "0" dentro de esos espacios vacios. Por ejemplo (1.000,2.000,3.000). Espero me haya explicado. Muchas gracias, les dejo mi codigo

```
              double x0, c, a, mod, tablaquintilla =0.0, tablapoker =0.0, 
              tablatercia = 0.0, tabladospares = 0.0, tablapar = 0.0, 
              tablapachuca = 0.0;
              double tablafull = 0;
                int n;
                char c1, c2, c3, c4, c5;
                double quin = 0.0, poke = 0.0, full = 0.0, ter = 0.0, dpar = 0.0, par = 0.0, pach = 0.0, chical;
                string compar;

                //VALORES DE LAS TABLAS PARA SHI EN POKER
                double pokertabla99 = 16.81;

                //RECOGEMOS LOS DATOS DE LAS CAJAS DE TEXTO

                x0 = Convert.ToDouble(txtSemilla2.Text);
                c = Convert.ToDouble(txtC2.Text);
                a = Convert.ToDouble(txtAlpha2.Text);
                mod = Convert.ToDouble(txtM2.Text);
                n = Convert.ToInt32(txtN2.Text);
                //DECLARAMOS NUESTRO ARRAY DE N NUMEROS PORQUE ESTOS SE ASIGNARAN CUANDO EL USUARIO TECLEE LA CANTIDAD
                double[] array = new double[n];
                //OBTENEMOS LA LISTA
                List<double> milista = new List<double>();

                //INICIAMOS EL CICLO PARA NUMEROS 
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {

                    //OBTENEMOS LOS NUMEROS PSEUDOALEATORIOS 
                    double result = (((x0 * a) + c) % mod);
                    x0 = result;
                    double resultado = Math.Round((result) / (mod - 1),6);
                    milista.Add(resultado);//PARA FINES MAS PRACTICOS QUE SE UTILIZARAN EN LAS DEMAS PRUEBAS GUARDAMOS EN UNA LISTA LOS RESULTADOS
                                           //UTILIZANOS UN ARRAY
                    array[i] = resultado;


                }
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {


                    c1 = Convert.ToChar(array[i].ToString().ElementAt(2));
                    c2 = Convert.ToChar(array[i].ToString().ElementAt(3));
                    c3 = Convert.ToChar(array[i].ToString().ElementAt(4));
                    c4 = Convert.ToChar(array[i].ToString().ElementAt(5));
                    c5 = Convert.ToChar(array[i].ToString().ElementAt(6));`
                    if (c1 == c2 && c1 == c3 && c1 == c4 && c1 == c5)
                    {
                        quin = quin + 1.0;
                        tablaquintilla = 0.0001 * n;
                    }
```

Comment: ¿Y porqué utilizas un textbox para capturar números? ¿codificas así con varias instrucciones por línea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias darle formato al string usando

```
string nroString = array[i].ToString("N3");

c1 = Convert.ToChar(nroString.ElementAt(2));
c2 = Convert.ToChar(nroString.ElementAt(3));
//resto codigo
```

al indicar el formato "N3" indicas que sera un numero con 3 decimales

[Cadenas con formato numérico estándar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Pero valida la cultura que estes utilizando, ya que si se trata de `ES-es` usara la coma como separador decimal, tienes que usar por ejemplo `En-us` para que use el punto como separador decimal

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, resolviste mi problema.